# Confusion about Scene and Object linking

Tags: objects, linked-data, scene, collections

I am making a marble maze simulation. In my main scene I am creating a bunch of modular "tracks" for the marble to run on. I currently have 150 or so objects.

What I want:

- To create a new scene (within the same .blend file) where I can "build" a track using the pieces from the original scene.
- This scene will only be used to move pieces around. I will not be editing the mesh data at all in this scene.

What I'm currently doing:

- I make a new piece, and then move it somewhere in the scene. Then I create another piece, and move that. It looks like this:

[image]

My confusion:

I tried creating a new linked scene, but I couldn't quite figure out how to build my test track without essentially copying all the objects. Since the scenes are linked, when I moved anything, it would be reflected in my original scene which is not what I want.

I feel like I am missing some information. When I create a new linked scene, how can I "remove" all the pieces I'm not using and just focus on moving around the ones I *am* interested in?

Comment: Maybe instead of using scenes, just put your original objects (all well arranged) in a collection, link-duplicate them in another collection, deactivate the original collection, use the duplications the way you want, when you want to go back to your original objects just reactivate the original collection. You could even use a View Layer with only this collection activated, this way you can easily switch from your 3D scene with your setup to the well arranged collection of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I've been stumped by this myself.
Took a long time to figure it out. Then forgot the solution and found your question while looking for the answer.
Anyway...
After linking the object to the second scene.
Select the object (in the second scene) and go to Object - Relations - Make single user - Object. 
Now it can be moved rotated and scaled but stil uses the same mesh and materals
If you want to use it multiple times in the second scene, make a linked copy there with Alt-d.
[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Make single users basically means turning links to duplicates, this isn't a solution.

Comment: Hi LOLock, The mesh is actually still the same. You can try this by editing the mesh in one scene and it will change in the other scene as well. So the mesh and materials are not duplicated.